# Content Restrictions

Tags: itunes

I was trying to download a song from iTunes, but a sign "this item can't be played because it contains explicit content" appeared on my screen. I allowed explicit content for Music in restrictions, but when i am trying to download the song again the same sign appears.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) I hope you come to find this site a valuable resource. In the meantime, can I ask you to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/339890/edit) your question to clarify whether we're talking about iTunes on a Mac, a PC, an iPhone etc? Also, how long did you wait between changing the restrictions and trying again?